# Uploading Image from Cloud Page

Tags: marketing-cloud

I'm trying to uploading an image from the marketing cloud page using the below code and update the published image path in the DE.

I'm able to upload image successfully into the content builder but unfortunately unable to update the published image path in the DE. When I try to print the published image path it's showing null.

Please do correct where went wrong, below is the code for reference.

```javascript
<script runat="server">
Platform.Load("Core","1.1.1");
try {
    //fetch posted data
    var jsonData = Platform.Request.GetPostData();
    var obj = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(jsonData);

    //prepare data for API call
    var base64enc = obj.base64enc;
    var fileName = obj.fileName;
    var assetName = obj.assetName;

    //match asset type with uploaded file (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/base-asset-types.htm)
    var assetTypes = { ai: 16, psd: 17, pdd: 18, eps: 19, gif: 20, jpe: 21, jpeg: 22, jpg: 23, jp2: 24, jpx: 25, pict: 26, pct: 27, png: 28, tif: 29, tiff: 30, tga: 31, bmp: 32, wmf: 33, vsd: 34, pnm: 35, pgm: 36, pbm: 37, ppm: 38, svg: 39, "3fr": 40, ari: 41, arw: 42, bay: 43, cap: 44, crw: 45, cr2: 46, dcr: 47, dcs: 48, dng: 49, drf: 50, eip: 51, erf: 52, fff: 53, iiq: 54, k25: 55, kdc: 56, mef: 57, mos: 58, mrw: 59, nef: 60, nrw: 61, orf: 62, pef: 63, ptx: 64, pxn: 65, raf: 66, raw: 67, rw2: 68, rwl: 69, rwz: 70, srf: 71, sr2: 72, srw: 73, x3f: 74, "3gp": 75, "3gpp": 76, "3g2": 77, "3gp2": 78, asf: 79, avi: 80, m2ts: 81, mts: 82, dif: 83, dv: 84, mkv: 85, mpg: 86, f4v: 87, flv: 88, mjpg: 89, mjpeg: 90, mxf: 91, mpeg: 92, mp4: 93, m4v: 94, mp4v: 95, mov: 96, swf: 97, wmv: 98, rm: 99, ogv: 100, indd: 101, indt: 102, incx: 103, wwcx: 104, doc: 105, docx: 106, dot: 107, dotx: 108, mdb: 109, mpp: 110, ics: 111, xls: 112, xlsx: 113, xlk: 114, xlsm: 115, xlt: 116, xltm: 117, csv: 118, tsv: 119, tab: 120, pps: 121, ppsx: 122, ppt: 123, pptx: 124, pot: 125, thmx: 126, pdf: 127, ps: 128, qxd: 129, rtf: 130, sxc: 131, sxi: 132, sxw: 133, odt: 134, ods: 135, ots: 136, odp: 137, otp: 138, epub: 139, dvi: 140, key: 141, keynote: 142, pez: 143, aac: 144, m4a: 145, au: 146, aif: 147, aiff: 148, aifc: 149, mp3: 150, wav: 151, wma: 152, midi: 153, oga: 154, ogg: 155, ra: 156, vox: 157, voc: 158, "7z": 159, arj: 160, bz2: 161, cab: 162, gz: 163, gzip: 164, iso: 165, lha: 166, sit: 167, tgz: 168, jar: 169, rar: 170, tar: 171, zip: 172, gpg: 173, htm: 174, html: 175, xhtml: 176, xht: 177, css: 178, less: 179, sass: 180, js: 181, json: 182, atom: 183, rss: 184, xml: 185, xsl: 186, xslt: 187, md: 188, markdown: 189, as: 190, fla: 191, eml: 192, text: 193, txt: 194, freeformblock: 195, textblock: 196, htmlblock: 197, textplusimageblock: 198, imageblock: 199, abtestblock: 200, dynamicblock: 201, stylingblock: 202, einsteincontentblock: 203, webpage: 205, webtemplate: 206, templatebasedemail: 207, htmlemail: 208, textonlyemail: 209, socialshareblock: 210, socialfollowblock: 211, buttonblock: 212, layoutblock: 213, defaulttemplate: 214, smartcaptureblock: 215, smartcaptureformfieldblock: 216, smartcapturesubmitoptionsblock: 217, slotpropertiesblock: 218, externalcontentblock: 219, codesnippetblock: 220, rssfeedblock: 221, formstylingblock: 222, referenceblock: 223, imagecarouselblock: 224, customblock: 225, liveimageblock: 226, livesettingblock: 227, contentmap: 228, jsonmessage: 230 };

    var assetTypeID = assetTypes[assetName];

    //authenticate to get access token
    var authEndpoint = 'https://XXXXXXXX'
    var payload = {
        client_id: "XXXX", 
        client_secret: "XXXX",
        account_id: "XXXX",
        grant_type: "XXXX"
    };
    var url = authEndpoint + '/v2/token'
  var contentType = 'application/json'

  var accessTokenRequest = HTTP.Post(url, contentType, Stringify(payload));
  if (accessTokenRequest.StatusCode == 200) {
    var tokenResponse = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(accessTokenRequest.Response[0]);
    var accessToken = tokenResponse.access_token
    var rest_instance_url = tokenResponse.rest_instance_url
  }
    //make api call to create asset   
    if (base64enc != null) {
        var headerNames = ["Authorization"];
        var headerValues = ["Bearer " + accessToken];
        var jsonBody = {
            "name": fileName,
            "assetType": {
                "name": assetName,
                "id": assetTypeID
            },
            "file": base64enc
        };

       var requestUrl = rest_instance_url + "asset/v1/content/assets"

       var createAsset = HTTP.Post(requestUrl, contentType, Stringify(jsonBody), headerNames, headerValues);
      
    }
  
var cAsset = (Stringify(createAsset));
var asset = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(cAsset);
var publishedUrl = asset.fileProperties.publishedURL; 
  
Write(Stringify(imgURL));  Write(Stringify(createAsset));
   
var rows = Platform.Function.InsertData("Upload",["createAsset","publishedUrl","Date"],[cAsset,publishedUrl,Now()]);

  
} catch (error) {
    Write("<br>error: " + Stringify(error));
}


</script>
```

Comment: I would check the response (Write the full response JSON returned from asset creation POST) to verify that the information is correctly in there and in the correct path of the returned Object. Sometimes returns encase it in a 'Response' array or similar that you need to account for when parsing out data from it.